# How safe encfs encrypted files are

Tags: encryption, encfs

Just recently got interested in encryption and some things are unclear. Say my ubuntu user is password protected and i have an encrypted folder. Now let's say someone takes my laptop, checks if i have encfs installed and because i have, he knows there are some encrypted files on the laptop. How hard would it be for that someone to get to those files?
The user password is fairly easy to bypass. I have read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption and as much as i understand that someone would have to know the location of the enrypted and visible folders and since he's already bypassed the user password he could also access those files using an encfs command right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first, I am recommending to use the manual command: man encfs. The encfs command makes an encrypted filesystem.

In case of `Single password mode` configuration it doesn't matter how strong is your filesystem encryption, if the hacker crack your easy login password. He will be also able to access your filesystem.

There are different cases when you have separate passwords for the login and the encrypted files/partitions, etc.

1. The whole SSD/HDD encrypted. In that case the attacker cannot access your file until he cracks your encFS password. In that case your user password is also encrypted.
2. Another case when the system partitions are not encrypted, but there are files/partitions which are. So in this scenario, an attacker can mount your sys partitions and may have access to your hashed, or encrypted password (by a password hash algorithm). But the attacker will not able to read your encrypted files/partitions until he brute forces the password of the encFS.

To answer your question:

If you used the laptop in Single Password mode with weak password, the likelihood is high, because you reused the weak password.

If you used 2 passwords and the encFS password is strong, it would be very hard to get those file.

Further information:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS

Comment: Thanks. Your answer confirms what i originaly thought - encryption is only good for outside intrusions and is as safe as your user password.

Comment: The encFs encrypted files have nothing to do with your user password. Of course there are security issues if someone can access your filesystem, but these are not covered by your answer.

Comment: You are wrong. If you take a closer look at the encFS's manual, you can find the following: `Note that when you are using try_first_pass parameter to pam_unix.so then you will have to set EncFS to use same password as you are using to login (or vice-versa) and you will be entering just single password. Without this parameter you will need to enter two passwords.`

We did not talk about eight's config, so we still don't now that, but I have to admit that in the default case, there are 2 passwords. 1 for login and 1 for the encrypted files, partition, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The encfs files are encrypted independently of your user account. This being said, if someone has access to your file system because of a weak user password, he could install some malware (keylogger or something).

Furthermore, [there are known securioty issues with encfs](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm), especially if someone can get various versions of your encfs encrypted files (which might be possible in this case).